# Numpy - Change first non-nan value in every row og ma

Tags: python, numpy, nan

I've got the following numpy-array:

```
a = np.full((8,8), np.nan)
a[:,2] = 0
a[::2,1] = 0

[[nan  0.  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan  0.  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan  0.  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan  0.  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan  0. nan nan nan nan nan]]
```

Now I want to replace the **first non-nan in every row** with `-1`. The result should look something like this:

```
[[nan  1.  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan  1. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan  1.  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan  1. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan  1.  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan  1. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan  1.  0. nan nan nan nan nan]
 [nan nan  1. nan nan nan nan nan]]
```

What would be an elegant way to do this?

Comment: `a[np.arange(len(a)),np.isnan(a).argmin(axis=1)] = -1`?

Comment: Yep, that does the trick. Care to promote your comment to an answer, so this thread can be closed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is guaranteed that each row has at least one non-nan entry:

```
a[np.arange(len(a)),np.isnan(a).argmin(axis=1)] = -1
```

This uses the fact that argmin chooses the first if there are tied minima.